# Handle custom pages for 401, 404 and 500 errors

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Dears,

My requirement is to handle 401, 404 and 500 server errors with custom error pages.
I have a solution in place but I'm seeking your expertise to pick the most optimal and best way to handle this.

**Application tech stack.**

My app is an SPA application built using Aurelia and .NET core.

**Use case:**

When the user directly hit an address on the browser, it first hits the server as the SPA is not loaded yet, and not possible to handle the client side routing.

**The solution I have implemented.**

I have implemented a middleware to handle the desired error responses

```
private async Task StaticErrorPageHandler(HttpContext context, Func<Task> next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next();
            var statusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
            var path = GetPathByStatusCode(statusCode.ToString());

            string content;
            switch (statusCode)
            {
                case StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized:
                    content = ReadFileContnet(path);
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(content);
                    break;
                case StatusCodes.Status404NotFound:
                    content = ReadFileContnet(path);
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(content);
                    break;
                case StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError:
                    content = ReadFileContnet(path);
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(content);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _loggingService.LogError<PortalStartupBase>(LogCategory.General, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And I have registered it as the first configured middleware for my application pipeline configuration.
( this way, I get the status code attached to the contex.response object)

```
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime lifetime, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        // configure middleware
        app.Use(StaticErrorPageHandler);
        ...
   }
```

So my question is, instead of short-circuiting the pipeline by writing prefered content to the context.response, can we redirect to a dedicated error controller?
like:

```
case StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized:
                    await context.Response.redirect("error/");
                    break;
```

Feel free to contact me should you require more info.

Appreciate your feedback in this regard.

~ RSF